# Using REGEXP_EXTRACT to get domain and subdomains

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have only managed to extract the TLD of the list of websites that I have using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Domain_name, r'(\.[^.:]*)]\.?:?[0-9]*$') AS web_tld
```

Example:

I have

```
www.example1.abc.com
www.example2.efg.123.net
```

I want the result

Subdomain

```
example1
efg
```

Domain

```
abc
123
```

TLD

```
.com
.net
```

EDIT:
Encountered an error in my query
'Exactly one capturing group must be specified'
when I use (.?([^.:]+).([^.:]+).([^.:]+):?[0-9]*$) as regex

```
SELECT
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Domain, r'(\.?([^.:]+)\.([^.:]+)\.([^.:]+):?[0-9]*$)'),
FROM [weblist.domain]
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 250;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can only use one capturing group, I think you can actually use 3 separate regular expressions to get the values you want:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Domain, r'([^.:]+):?[0-9]*$'),
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Domain, r'([^.:]+).[^.:]+:?[0-9]*$'),
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Domain, r'([^.:]+).[^.:]+.[^.:]+:?[0-9]*$')
FROM [weblist.domain]
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 250;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to encounter another error in my query when i use this regex

Answer (score 5):

Note you may be better off using the HOST, DOMAIN, and TLD rather than custom regular expressions.